# PNG with older browsers not looking good, iepngfix needed?

Tags: css, iepngfix

I have made some screenshots of my website, and in internet explorer 6 my website looks crappy (see screenshot)

I have heard something about a PNG fix, is a PNG fix the way to solve the crappy look? and can someone explain me how to implement this?

[Crappy look http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/e9/e91c994747851f0661ebc17d33e83201.png](http://api.browsershots.org/png/512/e9/e91c994747851f0661ebc17d33e83201.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original - http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/

Usage: http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/demo/

If you are using jQuery you can use the jQuery pluging - http://plugins.jquery.com/project/iepngfix

And don't forget to put the SCRIPT tags inside conditional comments

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>
//PNG FIX GOES HERE
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Those "fixes" only affect the rendering of PNG files with alpha masks. In your case, you have some serious layout problems in addition to the incorrectly rendered PNGs that will not be helped by them at all.

Comment: What do you mean? I used a 1024 resolution, maybe that's the problem, in all newer browsers the website looks good.

Comment: You're entitled to your opinion.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is in your opinion a serous layout problem?